# ndk-build.cmd: command not found

Tags: eclipse

(sorry for my bad english...)

I'm trying to build my .so library in Eclipse, with the CDT plugin. (It's an android project, with native code...)

Because I'm on windows, I replaced the build command in [Project->Properties->C/C++ build] with this one:

```
[absolute_path_to_android-ndk]\ndk-build.cmd V=1
```

But I got this message in the console:

```
C:\SDK\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build.cmd 
Cannot run program "C:\SDK\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build.cmd": Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
Error: Program "C:/SDK/android-ndk-r8/ndk-build.cmd" is not found in PATH
```

I tried with only "ndk-build.cmd" in the eclipse's build command, and the path to this command in my PATH environment variable, but I still have the same error.
In fact, I can't execute any program from the eclipse's build command.

I have no problem to build the library when I call ndk-build in cmd.exe, or in cygwin, but when I try to automate the library's build in Eclipse, it doesn't work...

Does anyone have a solution to my problem?

Comment: Can you run it from the shell if you type exactly C:\SDK\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build.cmd ?  Some permissions thing going on perhaps?  Does eclipse need a different or escaped directory separator?

Comment: Yes, I just tried again, by "pasting" C:\SDK\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build.cmd in windows shell, it works perfectly. :( I already tried with slashes instead of backslashes in eclipse, but the result is the same.

Comment: "In fact, I can't execute any program from the eclipse's build command."  That sounds like it might be a general trickiness for eclipse [version] on windows [version] far beyond Android usage, perhaps a web search would find a known answer?

Comment: I think so too. but this is the web search I'm making since this morning, with no results... ^^" that's why i'm posting.

Comment: You could try editing the question to make it a more general eclipse/windows one that doesn't require android expertise and see if you get interest from other eclipse users here

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by adding the NDK-path to the  path variable, in the ubuntu terminal as well as in eclipse. Then I had to DELETE THE ".cmd" in "ndk-build.cmd" because the terminal says that I have no permission with this file ending.